# Unexpected result for IF statement: "string" <= 72 is true?

Tags: perl

In my code below, when I enter in some non-numeric letters at the input (ie. `$temp`), it responds with "Too cold!" instead of "invalid". What am I missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "What is the temperature outside? ";
$temp=<>;
if ($temp > 72) {
  print "Too hot!\n"; }
elsif ($temp <= 72) {
  print "Too cold!\n"; }
else {
  print "Temperature $temp is invalid.\n"; }
```

Comment: Perl is a "weakly typed" language in this aspect. Be careful with operators lest coercions (like this!) bite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because it will be treated as 0 if it cannot be converted into a number. You should check before if the response has only numbers, or restrict the input in any other way so that only a valid number can be entered. Something along the lines:

```
print "invalid" if ($temp =~ /\D/);
```

(prints invalid if `$temp` contains any non-digit character. Note that this may invalidate "+" and "-", but you get the idea).

Comment: @kurotsuki - And get in the habit of using "use strict" and "use warnings" ;)

Answer (score 3):

The numerical comparison operators expect their arguments to be numbers. If you try to compare a string like `'foo'` using a numerical comparison, it will be converted silently to the number `0`, which is less than `72`.

If you had warnings turned on, you would have been told what was going on.

```
friedo$ perl -Mwarnings -E 'say "foo" < 72'
Argument "foo" isn't numeric in numeric lt (<) at -e line 1.
1
```

This is why you should always begin your programs with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Answer (score 2):

Casting an invalid numerical string to a number results in `0`, therefor you could use something as the below to see if the input was indeed valid or not.

```
print "What is the temperature outside? ";

$temp=<>;

if ($temp == 0 && $temp ne '0') {
  print "Temperature $temp is invalid.\n"; }
elsif ($temp > 72) {
  print "Too hot!\n"; }
elsif ($temp <= 72) {
  print "Too cold!\n"; }
```

*Explanation:* If the input string was casted into 0 (zero) though the string itself isn't equal to '0' (zero) the input is not numeric, hence; invalid.

---

You could also check to see if the input only consists of `[0-9.]` by using a regular expression, that would ensure that it's a valid number (also remember that numbers do not start with 0 (zero) and then have digits that follow, unless you are writing in octal.

*Note*: Remember to trim the input string from white spaces before the above check.

Answer (score 1):

For precisely this reason (and many others), you're MUCH better off if you enable "use warnings":

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it after removing the trailing newline, which is probably what's causing Perl to treat it as a string rather than a number:

```
chomp( my $test = <> );
```